# How to send a Python list as argument by reference to EnumChildWindows using the ctypes module?

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes, pywin32, win32gui

I have the following working Python code that uses the module `win32gui` to call the `EnumChildWindows` function:

```
import win32gui

def func(hwnd, param):
  param.append(hwnd)
  return True

def code():
  arr = []
  win32gui.EnumChildWindows(win32gui.GetDesktopWindow(), func, arr)
  print(arr)

code()
```

`win32gui.EnumChildWindows` allows to pass, by reference, any Python object in the last argument.

I'm trying to do the same using the module [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html). The closest I have gotten is passing a C array instead of the Python list, though it's not passing by reference because when I change the variable inside the function it doesn't change its value outside.

Code below:

```
from ctypes import byref, POINTER, windll, WINFUNCTYPE
from ctypes.wintypes import BOOL, HWND, LPARAM

def func(hwnd, param):
  c_arr = HWND * (len(param) + 1)
  param = c_arr(*param)
  param[len(param) - 1] = hwnd
  print(str(param[len(param) - 1]))
  return True

def code():
  py_arr = []
  c_arr = HWND * len(py_arr)
  arr = c_arr(*py_arr)
  WNDENUMPROC = WINFUNCTYPE(BOOL, HWND, HWND * len(py_arr))
  windll.user32.EnumChildWindows.argtypes = [HWND, WNDENUMPROC, POINTER(HWND * len(py_arr))]
  windll.user32.EnumChildWindows.restype = BOOL
  windll.user32.EnumChildWindows(windll.user32.GetDesktopWindow(), WNDENUMPROC(func), byref(arr))
  print(arr)

code()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a while of searching and trying different things, I found the code of [`win32gui`](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/master/win32/src/win32gui.i#L2141) in C.

It uses [PyObject](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.PyObject) which corresponds to [`ctypes.py_object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.py_object).

Working code below:

```
from ctypes import byref, py_object, windll, WINFUNCTYPE
from ctypes.wintypes import BOOL, HWND

def func(hwnd, param):
  param.append(hwnd)
  return True

def code():
  arr = []
  WNDENUMPROC = WINFUNCTYPE(BOOL, HWND, py_object)
  windll.user32.EnumChildWindows.argtypes = [HWND, WNDENUMPROC, py_object]
  windll.user32.EnumChildWindows.restype = BOOL
  windll.user32.EnumChildWindows(windll.user32.GetDesktopWindow(), WNDENUMPROC(func), arr)
  print(arr)

code()
```